# How can this aircraft be stable/maneuverable?

Tags: aircraft-design

The new wave of electric VTOL aircraft concepts (Joby Aviation, Zee, [Lilium](http://lilium-aviation.com/), Airbus A$^3$, etc...) has produced some audacious unconventional designs.

Now my question, is how Lilium's concept can be stable and/or maneuverable, given the following configuration:

[image: Lilium's concept]

What strikes me is a **lack of a surface** that creates a force to counteract the momentum generated by the distance between the wing's lift and the gravitational force.

And although control around the yaw axis seems possible with differential thrust, I wonder how the aircraft is controlled around the pitch axis.

From the forward part of the fuselage some canard-like surfaces with integrated propellers are deployed to provide hovering capabilities, however it seems these are supposed to be retracted during forward flight.

[image: Deployed "canard"]

---

Some might suggest the pictures are pure artwork, but Lilium and its investors appear to believe in the concept:
[image: First model]

[10m€ funding from London-based venture capital firm](https://medium.com/lilium-aviation/10million-funding-b49addcdfa71#.ex8p3ix7f)

Comment: Those images represent art, not engineering.

Comment: Must be an anti-gravity system. I don't think the wings would generate any lift with the motors in the way of the airstream.

Comment: @JonathanWalters At first glance, that's what I would think too. However, Lilium claims to be developing exactly this aircraft. Someone appears to believe in this: https://medium.com/lilium-aviation/10million-funding-b49addcdfa71#.udrqmr9nv

Comment: Well then, I would love to know the expected operating limitations for turbulence and wind gusts. I have trouble imagining such a design could handle conditions such as 20 gusting to 39, orographic turbulence, and low level wind shear very well. A calm-weather-only design?

Comment: Could be body of the aircraft be generating lift?

Comment: I was going to say it can't glide, but then I read it has a whole-airframe parachute, so I stand corrected.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: While I don't think the magnitude would be enough to solve the problem, if all of the weight of the motors *and* batteries were at the trailing edge of the wing, the CG might be further aft than it intuitively appears.  But probably not *enough* further.  It would seem like you could move the wing forward a fair amount while still maintaining good downward visibility, question is if it would be enough visibility for a vertical hover landing, or only an extremely steep descent.

Comment: http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2016/05/ducted_fans_on_wings/15974606-2-eng-GB/Ducted_fans_on_wings.jpg

Comment: I imagine that that beautiful thing will fly like a [shuttlecock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttlecock).

Comment: Some [clips of a test flight](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-39661299) were published in the media today, if that helps at all.

Comment: @RobieBasak just as fake as everything else about the thing. Note how the 'retractable forward surfaces' could never retract and leave room for a pilot's legs, or even at all because they together are wider than the room they have to retract into...

Comment: That test flight is clearly a scale model drone and it never retracts its forward "hovering" jets. It looks from the t if it did retract those it would nose down and fall quickly to its destruction. @Notts90 It does look like it might be designed as a lifting body.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

> What strikes me is a lack of a surface that creates a force to
>   counteract the moment generated by the distance between the wing's
>   lift and the gravity force.

You are not alone. Believe it or not, Lilium contacted me for advice, and I asked them basically the same thing. They never responded.

I agree with you, this thing will never fly and investors will get burned.

My advice to them would be to sweep the wings forward. This allows to keep the fuselage basically unchanged - you don't want the main spar to go where the pilot sits. But given the small wings this needs substantial sweep.

---

Update to this answer, February 2020:

Now they have beefed up their canard and skipped retractability, but all they can show is hovering flight for a few minutes at most. Sill no aerodynamic flight. The 300 km range and hour long flight time still are impossible with near-term technology. My verdict stands: Investors will get burned.

Comment: It's surprising that they would get to the full scale model without running wind tunnel tests or even modeling it in X-Plane to determine its characteristics. I'm guessing that this design would only work in VTOL configuration or where the front motors can act as a canard.

Comment: Their development page shows several flight tests, but all appear to have a forward ducted fan in the position where the circles are in the picture above:

http://lilium-aviation.com/development.html

Comment: "Lilium contacted me for advice..." -- we all knew Peter was good. I don't know that many of us knew he was _that_ good!

Comment: I'd only ask whether those "wings" are indeed wings, or just streamlined mounting pylons for the electric motors.  I also wonder why the artwork isn't showing the extension cord, 'cause there's not room for enough batteries for more than a few minutes of flight :-)

Comment: Maybe there's a few tons of batteries in the tail. `/eyeroll`

Comment: @SteveS so it's a multicopter with some things sticking out of it that look like wings to make the occupants feel better.

Comment: Their 2:1 scale demonstrator model is definitely flying as a multicopter, there's not enough forward motion.  It's not as heavy as the 300kg it should weigh either (as a 2:1 model).  I think the only viable strategy for them is to use the investment capital to first build a time machine, which they could then use to steal Graphene engineering technologies and Graphene lithium-ion batteries from the future.

Comment: @Adrian Thompson Phillips: I don't think even graphene lithium-ion batteries are going to provide enough energy.  They need to go sideways into the Star Trek universe and bring back a bunch of dilithium crystals :-)

Comment: "this thing will never fly and investors will get burned": it apparently does fly, according to [some short clips of a test flight](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-39661299) published in the media today. Looks like it is using downwards pointing fans rather than using the wings for lift.

Comment: @RobieBasak: Thanks for the link. What you see is something that uses its wings only to place propellers, but not to create lift, as you rightly say. It is flying slowly and the movie even loops back and forth to create the impression of a longer flying time. I do not see a reason to reverse my judgement.

Comment: [Here's a better video](https://youtu.be/ohig71bwRUE?t=49s) of their first drone flight

Comment: @Bergi: I wouldn't exactly call this flying - hovering yes, but not flying. For now the wings are purely for keeping the inefficient ducted props in place.

Comment: @SteveS I've seen many a kickstarter or similar website designed to lure venture capitalists and other investors with grandiose claims "supported" by videos and pictures that are clearly fakes to anyone with a bit of knowledge about physics or another related science exceeding primary school levels. This appear from the looks of it to be no different.

Comment: @m2as3registeredservicesohmone: They have **hovered** something that looks quite different to what it looked when I wrote this answer.

Comment: I guess buying an airline is not the only way to become  millionaire in aviation business...

Comment: It just goes to show one of my fundamental rules about aerospace: always beware of the Silicon Valley whiz kid claiming to be able to do what others have struggled to make for decades.

Comment: @PeterKämpf https://lilium-aviation.com/files/redaktion/refresh_feb2021/investors/Lilium_7-Seater_Paper.pdf a detailed performance assessment from Lilium.

Comment: @slitvinov What is needed is outside company engineers saying it will work, not based on the people asking for the money. If they want a vehicle that uses lift then that needs to be inherent in he design. We already know that blowing air at the ground really hard will get something off the ground. That isn't new technology. My issue with the pop out canard design is there is no place inboard to hide both of those units and then push them out, lock them into place to use them without being really heavy. Where do you put the the lever with nearly no space between the units when they are inboard?

Answer (score 28):

This looks a lot like many other similar technology projects which are really more designed to generate a fast buck by farming  grants and crowdfunding than with any realistic expectation of ever producing a working product.

Given that there is no technical detail apart from concept art and there are no remotely similar designs which *do* fly the question of *how* it *might* fly is purely speculative and there is no meaningful engineering data to comment on.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Looks like they've noticed their stability issues and are trying to update the design. Permanent fixed wing forward now and winglets the rear wings.

Comment: What wonderful progress. What will they think of next, a vertical tail?

Comment: Yes, T, with another set of ducted fans on it.

Answer (score 10):

Unless the body has some significant lifting properties, the nose will sink and the plane will not fly (without the canards extended).

In a no power situation, without a vertical stabilizer and some fore/aft lifting balance, this plane would be a lawn dart.

Answer (score 4):

It probably cant.
This wing configuration is designed for extreme performance, as in, its extremely unstable. Military planes are often unstable, which makes them turn faster.
Civilian planes are supposed to be stable, making them turn slow, comfortable, and safe.

Creating an unsafe air transport that is very uncomfortable and difficult to fly so to create dogfight capability for a civilian craft is either A: Madness, or B: attempt to make it look cool at the cost of everything else.
So its a scam for investors.

One possibility is that the top of the engine housing is designed to work as an elevator, but the question once again is "why?".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the third picture: look at the chord of wing and compare it to the attitude of the nose (angle of incidence). It is clear that the nose will point fairly high,  with a substantial amount of air hitting the belly of the aircraft, thus moving the centre of pressure forward, possibly close enough to the centre of mass.

There is an angle of incidence that neutralises the rotation around the pitch axis, although this does not result in a stable equilibrium condition. Some active control is required to avoid to flip the plane either downwards of backwards.

Comment: This is a comment (trying to convince myself), not an answer. -1

Comment: There is no way the nose can be very light since it's supposed to seat two people.

Comment: The lift, if there is any, could only emerge at high speed. Presumably you can get there from low speed regime without flipping over by pointing the front thrustors downward. But even then, it is going to be unstable.